# Cannot select vm size

Tags: azure, virtual-machines

I cant select virtual machine size while creating a virtual machine in free trial of azure Microsoft account.
How to see required size is available in which region.

Comment: Please provide more details including screenshots of what you are seeing.

Answer (score 1):

When you create a new VM you are presented with a Wizard, one of the steps of this wizard is to select the VM size.

However, Microsoft have stated that due to the current heavy demand in many regions (due to the Covid-19 crisis) that free accounts will not be given resources. This may be why you cannot see these sizes.